# How to mention If else condition in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Is there any code system like below :

```
@echo off  
set /p location=Type Folder Location  
copy "%location%\file.txt" "c:\Folder"  
if copy is done goto ok  
if not goto failed  
:ok  
echo File is copyed succesfully  
:failed  
echo File is not copyed  
echo.  
pause  
exit
```

Comment: What is your question.

Comment: my question is, the coad I have mentioned is correct or not, if not than what is correct format

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it. Code formating is more of a personal preference.

Comment: It's got invalid syntax if you have another look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off  
set /p location=Type Folder Location  
copy "%location%\file.txt" "c:\Folder"  
if errorlevel 1 goto failed  
:ok  
echo File is copied succesfully
goto done
:failed  
echo File is not copied  
:done
echo.  
pause  
exit
```

Normally, when a command succeeds, the "magic" variable `errorlevel` is set to zero; if it fails, to non-zero.

The syntax `if errorlevel n` will be true if `errorlevel` is `n` **or greater than n** (this last point is important - `if errorlevel 0` will always be true (in normal circumstances).

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.

(in this case, the `goto done` skips over the 'failed' message - often you want to terminate the batch under certain circumstances. *there* you'd use `goto :eof`)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Magoo saids in your case you just need 1 condition to go forward.
But to answer your question: **How to mention If else condition in batch file**

```
@echo off
set /a $var=1
if %$var%==1 (goto:ok) else (goto:nok)
:ok
echo OK
exit/b
:nok
echo NOK
```

You can change the value of `$var` to check it